# Unrecognized option '-Context' when running dotnet ef command

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, dotnet-cli

Starting a new project, and trying to set up the database for authentication.  I run the following command in powershell.
`dotnet ef database update -Context ApplicationDbContext`
and get the following error `Unrecognized option '-Context'`

So I try running it without the -Context option just to see and get:

```
More than one DbContext was found. Specify which one to use. Use the '-Context' parameter 
for PowerShell commands and the '--context' parameter for dotnet commands.
```

I also tried running it with --context instead of -context, but get the same error.  Any suggestions on why it recognizes that I need that option, but at the same time tells me it doesn't recognize the option?

I also restart powershell.

Comment: perhaps you need to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` and or `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` before that command will work?

Comment: @AndrewE I made sure all the required packages were installed.

Comment: instead of using `--context ApplicationDbContext` have you tried `-c ApplicationDbContext` also I had an issue once when I was trying to do a similar comment but I have to go up a directory in order for it to work,

Comment: @AndrewE Using -c did the trick.  If you want to add it as the answer I'll mark it accepted.  I don't understand why that worked, but in this case I'll take it.

Comment: fantastic, happy to help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `--context ApplicationDbContext` have you tried `-c ApplicationDbContext`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#aspnet-core-environment

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and instead of using `dotnet ef database update -Context ApplicationDbContext`, I replaced  `-Context` with `-c` which worked for me.